# Pattern validation expression, first letters capital in angular?

Tags: angular

I am working with an input field and I want the user first letter to be capital.
Before this, I needed a pattern that allows the user to put the only uppercase letter for that I used

```
pattern="[A-Z ]*"
```

Is there any pattern to check if the first letter of the user is capital.
The result I want is :

```
testing => is wrong
Testing => is good.
Testing Done =>is good also.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can use `/^[A-Z].*$/`.

`^[A-Z]` It mandates that the string should start with a capital letter.

`.*$` will now match anything except new lines.

```js
let regex = /^[A-Z].*$/
let str1 = 'testing'
let str2 = 'Testing'
let str3 = 'Testing Done'

console.log(regex.test(str1))
console.log(regex.test(str2))
console.log(regex.test(str3))
```

If you don't want to have capital letters in between the words then you can try:

```
 /^([A-Z][a-z]*((\s[A-Za-z])?[a-z]*)*)$/
```

```js
let regex = /^([A-Z][a-z]*((\s[A-Za-z])?[a-z]*)*)$/

let str1 = 'testing'
let str2 = 'Testing'
let str3 = 'Testing Done'
let str4 = 'TesTing';
let str5 = 'Testing Done Done Done done';

console.log(regex.test(str1))
console.log(regex.test(str2))
console.log(regex.test(str3))
console.log(regex.test(str4))
console.log(regex.test(str5))
```

**Note:** To use the pattern in angular you need to escape the backslash. SO you pattern will be something like:

```
Validators.pattern('^([A-Z][a-z]*((\\s[A-Za-z])?[a-z]*)*)$')
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3s3cdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I just test it for ''TesTing'' and works it should not @xyz

Comment: Maybe because that is js and not angular maybe sth bis diff there

Comment: @IliaTapia Check the updated answer. You need ask your question completely. You need to add all you want. Like, If you don't want a capital case in between a word, you need to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp = /^[A-Z]/
```

You can use the above code to validate your string.